# Can you explain the lyrics of "Hold on" by Jonas Brothers?

Tags: lyrics, reflexive-pronouns, implication

[Source](http://www.metrolyrics.com/hold-on-lyrics-jonas-brothers.html)

> 'Cause an empty room can be so loud
>   It's too many tears to drown them out

They mean to say **hold on because an empty room can be so loud**.Right?
What is **them**?

> When **it** falls apart, and you're feeling lost
>   All your hope is gone, don't forget to

If I am not wrong, then **it** is referred to **love**.

Comment: Also, **just hold on** could also be replaced by **only hold on**.Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lyrics like poetry, are open to interpretation.

The room is loud because with no one else in there, you can only hear your own thoughts. There is no distraction

"Them" is (imo) referring to those loud thoughts.

I agree, "it" refers to (lost) love.

"Hold on", probably means, it will get better, do not give up, there will be another love and friends to help you. -- Keep on going. Carry on.

"just hold on could also be replaced by only hold on" -- sure.

Answer (score 0):

> 'Cause an empty room can be so loud
>
> It's too many tears to drown them out

"Them" refers to the tears, I believe. "To drown out" means to make something impossible to hear by making some other, louder noise. So, the protagonist is trying and failing to drown out his tears, i.e. the sound of him crying, by blasting music in his room, alone. Hope it makes sense.

> When **it** falls apart, and you're feeling lost
>
> All your hope is gone, don't forget to

"It" doesn't refer to anything in particular here. "When it falls apart" simply means "when nothing is going right for you anymore". Also, song lyrics are rarely completely grammatically correct, so don't put too much thought into them, go for the overall meaning.

Comment: They could say, there's so many tears.

Comment: Also, just hold on could also be replaced by only hold on.Right?

Comment: I did not see reference to blasting music -- but to @AnubhavSingh -- this is exactly what I meant when I said lyrics and poetry are open to interpretation. I also think the thoughts are the loud "them", not the tears.